# How can I send send data to a component before it renders?

Tags: reactjs

I have a submit button that I want to redirect to another page without react routers. My button makes a request to Yelp Fusion but my content gets rendered before the data can be sent to my Game component.

Is there anyway I can make it wait until the http request is completed? What I had in mind was using an onChangeHandler constantly making requests so that I can save the data as we type instead of on submit but that seems overkill.

```
  // Function for accessing Yelp Fusion API
  const onSearchSubmit = async () => {
    const response = await yelp.get('/businesses/search', {
      params: {
        term: food,
        location: location
      }
    });
    // Saving our results
    setYelpResults(response.data.businesses);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Route path="/">
        <Home 
          handleFoodSearch={handleFoodSearch}
          handleLocationSearch={handleLocationSearch}
          onSearchSubmit={onSearchSubmit}
        />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/game">
        <Game yelpResults={yelpResults}/>
      </Route>      
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "content" is being rendered before you are ready? You are already awaiting the fetch request.

Comment: You can  create a variable initialized with a spinner (or whatever), when `onSearchSubmit()` has been executed, you only need to update the variable with the component that you need to render. Example: `var componetExample = <Spinner /> ... (at the of onSearchSubmit(): componentExample = <YourComponent />)`

Answer (score 0):

Could you set the `disabled` attribute on the property when you start the request, and remove it when finished? Something like (pseudocode):

```js
const onChangeHandler = async () => {
   myButton.disabled = true;
   await httpRequest();
   myButton.disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like that idea. I'm going to try that